# php not working on my VPS

Tags: php

This is my phptest.php file:

```
<?php
  echo "Hello";
?>
```

But when I try 'http://serveraddress/phptest.php'on my browser,it does not work properly and shows the whole php file on my browser.

I am using CentOS 5 and PHP version is 5.2.5. When a type 'php phptest.php' on the terminal, it works properly.

Please help

Comment: What web server are you using, Apache?  Ensure the PHP module for your web server is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a console run:

```
php -v
```

That should return the version of PHP if you have it installed. If you do have it installed, did you setup your web server properly to recognize PHP files? For example, you would need to add the following to your apache config file:

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
```

Comment: I added 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

But now when I try to run from the browser, it asks me to download the file. I am using Firefox 4.0

Comment: What was the result from running 'php -v' on the command line?

Comment: php -v gave

PHP 5.2.5 (cli) (built: Nov 19 2008 15:18:12) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2007 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2007 Zend Technologies

Comment: If PHP is installed on your system, merely adding the second line of code to your Apache configuration file solves the situation. Thanks David for this tip. In CentOS 7, it was located under `/etc/httpd/conf/` with the name `httpd.conf`. In that file, add that line of code inside the `IfModule mime_module` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

On redhat systems the apache configuration is by default held in one file /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. All modules are loaded from this file, and can be disabled by commenting out the appropiate LoadModule statement.

```
...
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
```

Check if your module isn't commented, restart apache.

Comment: On a CentOS 5 box?

Comment: I need to read more, edited the answer

Comment: You would have been better off leaving your Debian answer (after making it explicit it was Debian-specific) and then adding a second, CentOS-specific answer.